# AWS S3 + Cloudfront URL validation (CORS?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a bucket s3://my-bucket/ in where I have a lot of tenants there: s3://my-bucket/app1. s3://my-bucket/app2, s3://my-bucket/app3, etc...
I also have an AWS Cloudfront distribution with a custom domain pointing to this buckets as origin:

- app1.mycloudfrontcontenturl.com/app1/images/profilePicture.png
- app2.mycloudfrontcontenturl.com/app2/images/customLogo.png

The trick i'm interested to do is someone from app1 can not be able to their own files changing the host. I mean, in this scenario if you hit this someappX.mycloudfrontcontenturl.com/app1/images/profilePicture.png it works. I want to prohibit that, if the host header does not match with the app in the URL it should gives them forbidden or whatever.

Any idea that does not uses lambda@edge ?

Comment: Hi! to add CORS for that stack you need to enable CORS on the Cloudfront distribution and CORS on the S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi Luigi and thanks, and do you think this is the correct approach to have it done? I mean, with CORS can I achieve this I want?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it. To work with multi-tenant, no need to have several buckets, the S3 folders are enough.

Comment: @LuigiLopez exactly, but how can achieve this I want? To check the host header and match it with the folder?